# How to delete ALL directories but NOT files from another location in execv?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, rm, exec

Let's say I'm at the home directory and I have a directory called 'Apple' that has 2 directories (let's say I don't know their names) with contents in them and several files. I open my terminal in home, and I would like to delete those two directories inside 'Apple', without using cd.

I can't use **'rm -r home/Apple/*/'** nor can I use **'rmdir home/Apple/*'**.

Help?

Comment: If that's not a typo, the first command should be `rm -r /home/Apple/*`. You can also use `rm -rf`. Do you have permissions to delete the data?

Comment: @NasirRiley I'm reading it as if `Apple` has data in it that should _not_ be deleted.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's what I'm not clear on. The question only states that it has 2 directories with data inside that is to be deleted. It is isn't stated as to whether or not there's anything else or if he's just not sure as to how to only delete what he wants.

Comment: Hi sorry! Yes, I would like to remove the directories inside Apple with the data inside, but not the files inside Apple.

Comment: What is "execv"? You previously said "terminal" but now it seems like you may be executing the commands in some other way than interactively? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: @ilkkachu I know, but they use the `terminal` tag and never mention any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you by "the home directory" mean your home directory, i.e. `~`, the directory you end up with after executing `cd` with no arguments, not the directory `/home`.

You have two directories in `~/Apple` that you want to delete, lets call them `dir1` and `dir2`.  Assuming you also have other directories in there that you don't want to delete, you would use

```bsh
rm -rf ~/Apple/dir1 ~/Apple/dir2
```

to delete those two directories and all their content. If you are located in your home directory, then you could leave `~/` off the two pathnames in that command.

If those are the *only* directories in `~/Apple`, then you could possibly use

```bsh
rm -rf ~/Apple/*/
```

to delete all subdirectories of the `Apple` directory in your home directory.  The globbing pattern `*/` can only resolve to directories, so as long as you use that trailing slash, no non-directories in `Apple` would be affected.  Again, `~/` could be left off if you are located in your home directory.

You should obviously test this on data that is properly backed up so that you are able to restore it if you delete too much due to a mis-typing.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I seem to have gotten something like this:
"rm: cannot remove 'home/-myuser-/Apple/*/': No such file or directory
parent".

Comment: @Lunaxis Then your `Apple` directory contains no subdirectories.  Does it actually say `parent`?  Also, that path looks wrong. Did you use the command in my answer. I don't think you did. Note that I used `~/Apple/*/`, _not_ `home/Apple/*/` (or variations thereof). I'm confused because there is no initial `/` and the word `parent` at the end is a bit mysterious.

Comment: Ah I am sorry, and I don't know if this influences anything but I'm using execv.
rm: cannot remove '~/-myuser-/Apple/*/': No such file or directory
And yes I am sorry but it seems like parent was the start of a new error. Terribly sorry, very new in this!

Comment: @Lunaxis What do you mean with "using execv"? How are you executing these commands? I'm assuming that you're working at the command line, because you have said nothing else about it. If `rm` can't remove the given pattern, then there are no subdirectories under `~/Apple`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` to find all dirs directly inside Apple, and delete them

```
find home/Apple -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: You know that if you have a _user_ called `Apple` and if you execute this from `/`, you delete that user's home directory with this? You are also aware that you don't know whether "home directory" in the question means the user's home directory or the `/home` directory?  The command that you have posted will probably not work as intended unless you _carefully_ explain from where to run it.